# parse.com delete object ,by the way,delete the objects it relate to

Tags: ios, parse-platform, relationship

I created an relation from PFObject to anotherPFobject ,such as:

```
[relation addobject:object1];         
[mainObject setobject:relation forkey:@"relate"];         
[mainObject save];
```

the "relate" property is an one to many relationship;
Then,if i delete the mainObject

```
[mainObject delete];
```

what i want to konw is that how can i delete the objects  the "relate" property related to.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an afterDelete cloude code hook to accomplish this, per the guide here:
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-afterdelete

source: https://www.parse.com/questions/newb-trying-to-cascade-deletes

Comment: @Daij-Djan Does this use up an additional request?

Comment: @AlexanderofNorway Yes, it does.